# Run Android test on two (or more) Android versions with Robolectric

Tags: android, testing, junit, robolectric

I'm working on Android code that includes a differentiation between two Android versions.

I wrote tests to run the code. I'm using Robolectric.

I found a SO answer that says how to configure the version that Robolectric uses for running the test:
[Does Robolectric support API level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541630/robolectric-does-not-support-api-level)
But that way I'd have to copy the test and use different annotations (or rather have the test code in a private method and create two new public test methods that call the private method - but I've already got hundreds of tests, so this would be lots of work).

Is there any way to tell Robolectric to run a test twice, with different Android versions for each run?

Answer (score 3):

I know your answer has been posted a year ago but I had the same problem and I found no answer on the web.

I found a solution with Robolectric 3.0 : you can use the class `MultiApiRobolectricTestRunner`. For example :

```
@RunWith(MultiApiRobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, manifest=Config.NONE, sdk = {16, 19, 21})
public class MyTestCase extends TestCase {

    @Test
    public void test1ToRunOnMultipleApis(){
        // My test
    }
}
```

The method `test1ToRunOnMultipleApis` will be tested 3 times : with API 16, 19 and 21.

Hope this can help ;)